# In App Purchases: getting a token before a purchase is completed

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

In app purchasing for my app is special, i.e. the server has to deliver some content after purchasing. Now when something happens immediately after the user did the in app purchase (e.g. network connection gets lost) the server does not find out about the purchase. iOS provides the idea of receipts which enables the server to check periodically if a specific user did a purchase. Is there something available for Android as well?

E.g.

```
User wants to buy something
send token/receipt/whatever to my server
connection gets lost here
```

Now the server knows that it received the token but the purchase wasn't finished, so it can periodically check with the token if the purchase was completed by the user and if yes, deliver the content.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to retrieve the purchases of the user when the app starts using the [In-App billing library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html) and send a request to the server for those that had failed earlier.

Of course, you'll need some kind of local database (SQLite, or use *shared preferences*) to store those that failed and those that were redeemed successfully.

---

In my app, here's what I do:

1. Get the "Premium status" from my server
2. Get the Premium status using In-App billing
3. If the server says *not premium* and client says *premium*, the client sends the purchase token (provided by In-App billing) to my server that verifies it. If verification is successful, the client saves the information locally. (of course, each time the app is started, the *premium status* is retrieved again because the server is the authority!)